# How does this searching work in Perl?

Tags: perl

```
my ($len, $longest) =0;
length > $len and ($longest, $len)=($_, length) for @matches;
```

`@matches` stores some substrings. This code catches the longest substring from `@matches`, then stores it in `$longest`.

Source code:

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $needle = "axibidm";
my $haystack = "axididm";
my @matches;


for my $start (0..length $needle) {
for my $len (1 .. ((length $needle)-$start)) {
    my $substr = substr($needle, $start, $len);
       push @matches, $haystack =~ m[($substr)]g;
    print "$substr\t";
    print "@matches\t\n";
  }
}

my ($len, $longest) = 0;

length > $len and ($longest, $len) = ($_, length) for @matches;


print "The longest common substring between\n", $needle, "\nand\n", $haystack, "\nis '$longest'\n";
```

Comment: Is there something specific you don't understand about that snippet? (As an aside, I don't blame you for not understanding, there are much clearer ways that could be written.)

Comment: The thing to know is that length called without an argument returns the length of the $_ variable. If I saw this in code I was working on, I would ask the author of this to rewrite it into legible code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73871/discussion-between-schwern-and-ikegami).

Answer (score 3):

Someone was being far too clever, or they made a typo.  Or both.  Probably both.

There's some things going on with that code which don't do what it appears to be doing.  This does not initialize both variables to zero.

```
my ($len, $longest) = 0;
```

Its a deceptive way to write this.

```
my $len = 0;
my $longest;
```

`for $matches` is silly, there's only one thing to iterate over so why use a loop?  This idiom is very occasionally used to put the value into `$_` and use it in various default constructs, but that's not much use here.

Next, the following is a very tortured way to write `do this if that`.  It's written that way to make it a single expression which will work within the for loop statement modifier.

```
length > $len and ($longest, $len)=($_, length)
```

It is much better written like this.

```
if( length > $len ) {
    $longest = $_;
    $len = length;
}
```

Expanding it out, and removing the useless for loop, we get...

```
my $len = 0;
my $longest;

if( length $match > $len ) {
    $longest = $match;
    $len = length $match;
}
```

The other option is that `$matches` is an array references and they meant `for @$matches`.  `for $matches` would still "work" but it would always return a length of 21 because an array reference stringifies as something like `ARRAY(0x7fc07c800468)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, It should be @match. Sorry I'm pretty new to Perl and stackoverflow.

Comment: @raymondxuym Would you edit the question please to clear up the confusion?

Comment: @raymondxuym Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you post questions, please make sure to copy and paste the exact code you're running to avoid misunderstandings like this.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thank you for your advice. I just attached all the source code. Thank you!

Comment: @raymondxuym You're welcome. Just to clarify slightly: if you have a lot of code, instead of copying it all into your question, you should make a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem and copy and paste *that* into your question. It takes some extra work, but often in the process of making the example, you find your solution yourself. Good luck with your future questions!

Answer (score 1):

That looks almost deliberately obfuscated. Here's a more verbose expression of the same logic.

```
my $len = 0;
my $longest;

foreach my $match (@matches) {
  if (length($match) > $len) {
    $longest = $match;
    $len = length($match);
  }
}
```

So let's compare.

```
my ($len, $longest) = 0;
```

This declares the two lexical (`my`) variables `$len` and `$longest`, and sets the first one (`$len`) to 0, leaving `$longest` at its default value of `undef`.

This structure:

```
 (code goes here) for @matches;
```

is the same as this:

```
 for (@matches) {
     (code goes here)
 }
```

So we're iterating over the `@matches` array and running the code once per element.  Within the body of the code, the special variable `$_` will hold the current element.

```
length > $len and ($longest, $len) = ($_, length);
```

First, `(expression) and (code)` is a shorthand way of writing `if ( (expression) ) { (code) }`.  It works because in Perl, `and` is evaluated left-to-right in a short-circuiting fashion.  That is, if the left side expression is false, Perl doesn't bother evaluating the right side, since its value doesn't matter; `false and` anything is `false`.

When `length` is called without an argument, it means `length($_)`, so that's the length of the current element of `@matches` that is being examined.

And `($var1, $var2) = ($val1, $val2)` is parallel assignment that sets `$var1` to `$val1` and `$var2` to `$val2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
EXPR for LIST;
```

is roughly the same as

```
for (LIST) { EXPR; }
```

---

```
EXPR1 and EXPR2;
```

is roughly the same as

```
if (EXPR1) { EXPR2; }
```

(This is not a generally accepted practice, except when `EXPR2` is a flow control expression (`next`, `die`, etc).)

---

`length` defaults to using `$_` as its argument (`length($_)`).

---

```
( $x, $y ) = ( EXPR1, EXPR2 )
```

is roughly the same as

```
$x = EXPR1;
$y = EXPR2;
```

(One notable difference is that you can do `($x,$y)=($y,$x)` to swap values, but that's used here.)

(Using a list assignment when two scalar assignments would do is also not a generally accepted practice.)

---

A more conventional way of writing the code would be:

```
my $len = 0;
my $longest;
for (@matches) {
   if (length($_) > $len) {
      $longest = $_;
      $len = length($_);
   }
}
```